# Repeating a query does not refresh the properties of the returned objects

Tags: nhibernate, session, caching

When doing a criteria query with NHibernate, I want to get fresh results and not old ones from a cache.

The process is basically:

1. Query persistent objects into NHibernate application.
2. Change database entries externally (another program, manual edit in SSMS / MSSQL etc.).
3. Query persistence objects (with same query code), previously loaded objects shall be refreshed from database.

Here's the code (slightly changed object names):

```
public IOrder GetOrderByOrderId(int orderId)
{    
...
IList result;
var query = 
    session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Order))
        .SetFetchMode("Products", FetchMode.Eager)
        .SetFetchMode("Customer", FetchMode.Eager)
        .SetFetchMode("OrderItems", FetchMode.Eager)
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("OrderId", orderId));
query.SetCacheMode(CacheMode.Ignore);
query.SetCacheable(false);

result = query.List();
...
}
```

The SetCacheMode and SetCacheable have been added by me to disable the cache. Also, the NHibernate factory is set up with config parameter UseQueryCache=false:

```
Cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.UseQueryCache, "false");
```

No matter what I do, including Put/Refresh cache modes, for query or session: NHibernate keeps returning me outdated objects the second time the query is called, without the externally committed changes. Info btw.: the outdated value in this case is the value of a Version column (to test if a stale object state can be detected before saving). But I need fresh query results for multiple reasons!

NHibernate even generates an SQL query, but it is never used for the values returned.

Keeping the sessions open is neccessary to do dynamic updates on dirty columns only (also no stateless sessions for solution!); I don't want to add Clear(), Evict() or such everywhere in code, especially since the query is on a lower level and doesn't remember the objects previously loaded. Pessimistic locking would kill performance (multi-user environment!)

Is there any way to force NHibernate, by configuration, to send queries directly to the DB and get fresh results, not using unwanted caching functions?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: this doesn't have **anything** to do with second-level caching (which is what `SetCacheMode` and `SetCacheable` control). Even if it did, those control caching of the query, not caching of the returned entities.

When an object has already been loaded into the current session (also called "first-level cache" by some people, although it's not a cache but an [Identity Map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html)), querying it again from the DB using any method will **never** override its value.

This is by design and there are good reasons for it behaving this way.

If you need to update potentially changed values in multiple records with a query, you **will** have to `Evict` them previously.

Alternatively, you might want to read about [Stateless Sessions](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-statelesssession).

Answer (score 0):

Is this code running in a transaction? Or is that external process running in a transaction? If one of those two is still in a transaction, you will not see any updates.

If that is not the case, you might be able to find the problem in the log messages that NHibernate is creating. These are very informative and will always tell you exactly what it is doing.

> Keeping the sessions open is neccessary to do dynamic updates on dirty columns only

This is either the problem or it will become a problem in the future. NHibernate is doing all it can to make your life better, but you are trying to do as much as possible to prevent NHibernate to do it's job properly.

If you want NHibernate to update the dirty columns only, you could look at the [`dynamic-update`-attribute](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#mapping-declaration-class) in your class mapping file.